# How to filter for a date column in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I want to use ag-grid and i have a date column with the following format

```
dd.mm.yyyy
```

I want to click on a button and filter the data for column where date `< 'today + 30 days'`, so if it is within the next 30 days.

How could i do this? I have no idea how to filter a plaintext column based on the requirement above.